# Java - JSON Null Exception

Tags: java, json, exception, null

I'm using JSON to deserialize an input string that contains a `null` value for certain hashmap property. Does anyone have any clue why this exception occurs ? Is it possible that `null` is not accepted as a value Is this configurable somehow ?

input sample:

```
{"prop1":"val1", "prop2":123, "prop3":null}
```

stacktrace:

```
net.sf.json.JSONException: null object
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.verifyIsNull(JSONObject.java:2856)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.isEmpty(JSONObject.java:2212)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me this works with json-lib-2.3-jdk15:

```
String json = "{\"prop1\":\"val1\", \"prop2\":123, \"prop3\":null}";
JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, HashMap.class);
```

Actually the `null` value becomes an instance of `JSONNull`.

> `JSONNull` is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls `null`, whilst Java's `null` is equivalent to the value that JavaScript calls `undefined`.