# Java, Parse JSON Objects that I know are null

Tags: java, json, exception, null

I have an array of JSON objects. To parse these arrays and store the simply data type values, I have to make assumptions of the key names and store them accordingly.

I also know that sometimes the key's values will be null.  example `{["promotion":null]}` how would I parse this?

If I try to access a key whose value is null, I get a JSONException. Now this makes sense, but even if I do `if(myJSObject.getString("promotion")!=null)` then I will still get JSON exception when it checks

how would I do a conditional check in my code for null objects so that I can avoid the JSON exception

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456078/java-json-null-exception

Comment: the answer wouldn't work for me, I can't just use a hashmap because my objects have more than two values to just store. More like 5 or 6 unique key/value pairs

Comment: Ah, so your JSON would need to look more like [{"key1":val1},{"key2":val2},{"key3":val3}], then iterate through the array of objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `JSONObject.optString(String key)` or `optString(String key, String default)`.

Edit: ... or `isNull(String key)`, of course :)

Comment: Also check out the other `opt...(key)` methods for different data types or the general `Object opt(key)`.

Comment: optString("promotion",null) returns "null" (not null!) in my case for {"promotion":null}, which I consider to be strange. Javadoc says that null is returned for missing keys, otherwise conversion is made. Probably it is the reason why I get "null" instead of expected null. Seems that I will have to apply the check isNull(), what I tried to avoid. Bad designed API, you poor javascripters! ))

Comment: @Pang Thanks for the ping! json.org stopped hosting javadoc, so here's a link to the source code for `org.json.JSONObject`: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to format the JSON differently;

for an array of promotions

```
{promotions:[{promotion:null}, {promotion:5000}]}
```

for a single promotion

```
{promotion:null}
```

edit: depending on which json api you're using, there might be a null check. Google's gson library has an `.isJsonNull()` method

Answer (score 0):

Uh...I don't think that is a properly formatted JSON string. [] indicates an array, which doesn't have any kind of key=>value pairing like an object does. What I think you want would be `{"promotion":null}`, which then your code snippet likely would work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JSON array can't have pairs, just values. See http://json.org/. So ["promotion":null] is invalid JSON.