# JSonException with null value

Tags: android, json, exception

I'm having lots of problems when parsing a JSon and one of it's values has null value.

```
{
"available_from" : "2012-11-05T00:00:00Z",
"available_to" : "2012-11-30T00:00:00Z",
"category_id" : 2,
"created_at" : "2012-11-05T14:53:39Z",
...
}
```

For example if "category_id" equals null I get an exception on my parser. What can I do to solve it?

Hope I've explained myself..

Comment: Also posting your error log would help

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/7506030/1134705

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before trying to get a value from the JSONObject you need to check if it has the key and if the value is not "null".

Add this If statement every time you try to access a certain key:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
if(jsonObject.has("category_id")&&!jsonObject.isNull("category_id")){
   String s = jsonObject.getString("category_id");      
}
```

Comment: in addition to this answer: think about writing your own utility class that does the has(name) and !isNull(name) for you - simplifies your code a lot

Comment: You mean by making some method that takes a JSON Object, and a String key as parameters and returns jsonObject.has(key)&&!jsonObject.isNull(key) 
?

well I think that all the parsing should be in a separate class.

Comment: either that to do the null check or to return the value as string, integer etc. (as equivalence to the getString on the jsonObject itself)

Comment: It might be a good idea, to make a utils class with that. But aren't all these method calls will slow down the application? lets say I need to parse a list of 30 objects, then I will need to do around 30*4 method calls + some more calls at the start.

Comment: you can also use optString("category_id",null) - see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Considered using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)? It really simplifies JSON parsing. Also if you are using regular jsonobjects the values may not be null. Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for further info.