# using Json file in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to import a json file and use the data inside it and export the file as json file

Use the file `movies.json` to initialize the Movie Library, and export a modified Json file to save the library upon completion of the program.

```
private Vector<MovieDescription> libraryList = new Vector<MovieDescription>();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        MovieLibrary movies = new MovieLibrary();

        // Input the group from movies.json

        System.out.println("Importing group from movies.json");

        MovieLibrary movies1 = new MovieLibrary("movies.json");

        movies1.add(new MovieDescription("Suicide Squad", "PG-13", "05 August 2016", " 2h 3min",
                "Fearing that the world is vulnerable to otherworldly threats, the Government enlists the disposable Task Force X on a high-risk mission in exchange for absolution: Meanwhile, the Joker operates his own agenda.",
                "Suicide Squad.mp4", "Action, Adventure, Crime", " Will Smith, Jared Leto, Margot Robbie "));

        movies.add(new MovieDescription("Sausage Party", "R", "12 August 2016", "1h 29min",
                "The products at Shopwell's Grocery Store are made to believe a code that helps them live happy lives until it's time for them to leave the comfort of the supermarket and head for the great beyond. However, after a botched trip to the great beyond leaves one sausage named Frank and his companion Bun stranded, Frank goes to great lengths (pun intended) to return to his package and make another trip to the great beyond. But as Frank's journey takes him from one end of the supermarket to the other, Frank's quest to discover the truth about his existence as a sausage turns incredibly dark. Can he expose the truth to the rest of the supermarket and get his fellow products to rebel against their human masters?",
                "Sausage Party.mp4", "Animation, Adventure, Comedy", " Seth Rogen, Kristen Wiig, Jonah Hill"));

        movies.add(new MovieDescription("Deadpool", "R", "12 February 2016", "1h 48min",
                "A former Special Forces operative turned mercenary is subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopting the alter ego Deadpool. ",
                "Deadpool.mp4", "Action, Adventure, Comedy", " Ryan Reynolds, Morena Baccarin, T.J. Miller"));

        movies1.printLibrary();

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("moviesJava.json");

        out.println(movies1.toJSONString());

        out.close();

        System.out.println("Done exporting group in json to movies.json");

        // now use java's built in serialization to serialize and
        // deserialize

        File outFile = new File("movies.ser");

        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));

        os.writeObject(movies);

        os.flush();

        System.out.println("Used Java serialization of the group to movies.ser");

        os.close();

        File inFile = new File("movies.ser");

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));

        MovieLibrary movieAgain = (MovieLibrary) in.readObject();

        System.out.println("Done importing the group from movies.ser as:");

        movieAgain.printLibrary();

        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("exception: " + e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

and this is the `toJsonString` method

```
public String toJSONString() {

    String ret;

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    for (Enumeration<MovieDescription> e = libraryList.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {

        MovieDescription movi = (MovieDescription) e.nextElement();

        try {

            obj.put(movi.getTitle(), movi.toJson());
            /*
             * obj.put(movi.getActors(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getFilename(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getGenre(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getPlot(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getRated(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getReleased(),movi.toJson());
             * obj.put(movi.getRuntime(),movi.toJson());
             */

        } catch (JSONException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    ret = obj.toString();

    return ret;

}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> ```
> org.json.JSONException: Null key.
> at org.json.JSONObject.put(JSONObject.java:1097)
> at MovieLibrary.toJSONString(MovieLibrary.java:124)
> at MovieLibrary.main(MovieLibrary.java:69)
> ```

Comment: can you indicate in your code where line 124 and 69 in `MovieLibrary.java`

Comment: It seems that `movi.getTitle()` returns null. Can you verify that ?

Comment: its pretty obvious its in the put command in toJSONString method. I guess you have null in `movi.getTitle()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239439/jsonexception-with-null-value

Comment: yes it is because of null but I want the information that inside movies.json to be add to the library instead of the null value can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way of doing this is by using Jackson.

Create class MovieLibrary with getter and setter methods for each variable inside it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MovieLibrary movies = new MovieLibrary();
//Object to JSON in file
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\file.json"), movies);
```

The above code will map the data in the file to object of MovieLibraary(movies). You can modify the value in movies object by using setter methods.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/